# 1093 error when running mysql query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run this query

```
UPDATE xxxxx_k2_categories SET params = (SELECT params FROM xxxxx_k2_categories WHERE alias = 'bread') WHERE parent = 1 MySQL
```

But am getting a 1093 error. I know this is because I am trying to update a table from it's own values but i don't know Mysql very well. Although this is really helping me learn :)

Any help is most appreciated.

This is my data.

```
Alias Parent Params Bakery 0 {Test Params 1} Bread 1 {Test Params 2} Rools 1 {Test Params 3}
```

I want to copy the value in params for item 'bread' to all rows that have a value of parent of '1'

Comment: is `MySQL` at the end of the query a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `join` instead:

```
UPDATE xxxxx_k2_categories x cross join
       (SELECT params FROM xxxxx_k2_categories WHERE alias = 'bread') b
    SET x.params = b.params
    WHERE parent = 1;
```

Comment: Wow Gordon. Thank you sooooooo Much. Worked like a charm. I realised i had made a small error in my requirements but i just changed the = 1 to > 0

Answer (score 0):

Does
SELECT params FROM xxxxx_k2_categories WHERE alias = 'bread'

return more than 1 record?
if so that could be the problem